# Can I schedule a one-shot action in openwhisk?

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, serverless-framework, openwhisk

I'm playing a bit with openwhisk in IBM Bluemix and now I'm looking for a way to shedule a one shot action.

I know I can run actions at fixed intervals, in a "cron" fashion using 'feed /whisk.system/alarms/alarm'. What I am looking for is similar to the `at` linux command.

The closest I figured out involves another server used to generate events, but I would like to be as "serverless" as possible.

Another non desirable solution would be using js `setTimeout` but... I suppose that would waste execution time. (And possibly hitting execution time limit)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the alarm to schedule a single trigger at a specific date. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yes, it isn't ideal but it will do it. Do you mean using `maxTriggers 1` ? I somehow overlooked that. Thank you very much. If you wish to write that as a response I will accept it.

Comment: Well, I have to check if "used" actions are automatically deleted, (I suppose they are) If not it could be a little troublesome.

Comment: The action itself is not deleted. Actually neither is the trigger or rule. Do you really intend for these to be one and done?

Comment: Oh I don't want the actions to be deleted, I meant triggers, sorry.

Comment: Let's see an example of what I'm trying to do: I want to access 20 or 30 URIs in a site, but I don't want to get banned or get 429 (too many requests) errors, so I (throttle is the term?) try to send requests spaced by several seconds... Normally I would use `setTimeout` but with openwhisk I don't want my action to run for very long. Maybe this is not an apropriate workload for openwhisk? By the way, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why not use a schedule then of once an hour or so?

Comment: What do you mean Raymond? Maybe I didn't explain well. I wan't to wait like a couple of seconds between requests. I mean: I want to read once or twice a day 20 or so URIs with couple of secs in between. At the time being I'm using setTimout and works just fine, but my function takes like 40secs being > 90% of that time just waiting for timeouts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cron schedule with appropriate fields and the `maxTriggers` parameter set to 1.

The `maxTriggers` parameter ensures that, after a single event, the trigger won't be called again.

One-off triggers can be created from the command-line.

Here's an example for a trigger to run once at 1st January @ 00:00.

```
wsk trigger create new_year --feed /whisk.system/alarms/alarm
  -p cron '0 0 1 0 *' 
  -p maxTriggers 1 
  -p trigger_payload '{"message":"Happy New Year!"}'
```

*There is an open issue in the open-source repo to provide better support for these kind of events.*
https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-package-alarms/issues/89